# CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

Hi i'm creating a Keyframe animation from multiple images. My problem is i would like the animation to instantly change from one image to the next rather than a fade.

```
    CALayer *animLayer = [CALayer layer];
    animLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    animLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *customFrameAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    NSArray *sizeValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)image1, (id)image2, nil];
    NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f], nil]; 
    NSArray *timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault], [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault], nil];

    [customFrameAnimation setValues:sizeValues];
    [customFrameAnimation setKeyTimes:times];

    customFrameAnimation.duration=5.0;
    customFrameAnimation.beginTime = 1e-100;
    customFrameAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
    customFrameAnimation.timingFunctions = timingFunctions;
    customFrameAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [animLayer addAnimation:customFrameAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your animation will need its calculationMode set to kCAAnimationDiscrete.

Take a look at the [documentation on keyTimes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAKeyframeAnimation/keyTimes) which describes how the calculationMode is used:

> The appropriate values in the keyTimes
> array are dependent on the
> calculationMode property.
>
> - If the calculationMode is set to
>   kCAAnimationLinear, the first value in
>   the array must be 0.0 and the last
>   value must be 1.0. Values are
>   interpolated between the specified key
>   times.
> - If the calculationMode is set
>   to **kCAAnimationDiscrete**, the first
>   value in the array must be 0.0.
> - If the
>   calculationMode is set to
>   kCAAnimationPaced or
>   kCAAnimationCubicPaced, the keyTimes
>   array is ignored.
>
> If the values in the
> keyTimes array are invalid or
> inappropriate for the calculationMode,
> the keyTimes array is ignored.

And then you can read the description of the calculation modes:

> **Value calculation modes**
>
> These constants are used by the
> calculationMode property.
>
> NSString * const kCAAnimationLinear;
>
> NSString * const kCAAnimationDiscrete;
>
> NSString * const kCAAnimationPaced;
>
> **Constants**
>
> *kCAAnimationLinear*
>
> Simple linear
> calculation between keyframe values.
> Available in Mac OS X v10.5 and later.
> Declared in CAAnimation.h.
>
> *kCAAnimationDiscrete*
>
> Each keyframe value is used in turn, no interpolated
> values are calculated.
> Available in
> Mac OS X v10.5 and later.
> Declared in CAAnimation.h.
>
> *kCAAnimationPaced*
>
> Keyframe values are interpolated to produce an even
> pace throughout the animation.
> Available in Mac OS X v10.5 and later.
> Declared in CAAnimation.h.

In other words, the discrete calculation mode makes the animation jump to each key frame rather than animate/transition to it.

Best regards.